# При загрузки системы из загрузчика GRUB пропала windows и осталась Fedora

Tags: linux, fedora

При попытки ввести sudo update-grub [image: выдает ошибку и не видит другие системы]

К тому же, на федоре пропали все файлы

Comment: Что вы делали до того как у вас всё пропало?

Comment: Попробуй посмотреть через эту утилиту, видит ли система Винду. `sudo os-prober`

Comment: `update-grub` - только в debian\ubuntu. В `rpm` такого счастья нет.

Comment: @MiMEKiZ вечером отличили свет, а на утро обнаружилось это. При попытке зайти в другие места, пишет ошибки.

Comment: @B1aZe Я прописывала, виндовс видит, но update-grub  не работает

Comment: Вам нужен Live CD с виндой или сама винда, которая у вас установлена(именно такая же, с такой же разрядностью) и там выбрать исправить ошибки, скорее всего, что после аварийного выключения компьютера, раздел MBR с виндой повредился, по этому загрузить винду у вас не получается.

Comment: @B1aZe Но как выбрать?

Answer (score 0):

Сегодня так же столкнулся с данной проблемой, после установки Debian.
Как лечил:

1. Запписываем на USB Windows, желательно такой же разрядности, дабы
   перестраховатся.
2. Грузимся с данной USB дабы войти в меню установки.
3. Нажимаем внизу "Востановление системы". Если у вас Windows 7, переходим к пункту 5.
4. Далее нажимаем "Поиск и устранение неисправностей".
5. Командная строка.

В командной строке вписываем `diskpart`, затем `list volume`. Нам покажет разделы которые у нас есть в системе, главное найти наш раздел с Windows.

После пишем в той же консоли `bcdboot x:\windows`, где `x` это разздел где установлена Windows. Далее пишем `exit`и перезагружаем систему. Теперь наша Windows будет грузится всегда первой. Для того, чтобы переключится на Linux, нужно указать в BIOS или же если у вас UEFI нажать при загрузки соответствующую клавишу, чтобы указать откуда стоит грузить систему, но это в том случаи, если у вас Linux и Windows стоят на разных дисках. Если же нет, то придётся дописывать загрузку Linux в загрузчик.